# Why does Android Studio Kotlin Compose Template display text wrong when app is run?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I built an app from the Android Studio template using the new Compose feature ([official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/kotlin)).

The Preview looks like the following:

[image: Android Compose preview]

However, when I run the application, it looks like this (text is much smaller & is not centered in the View):

[image: Android Compose running example]

Is that not an actual Preview of the UI in the editor?
Is there a way to do a true preview of Compose in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

[Jetpack Compose Preview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#preview) shows only the elements contained in the function that has the annotation, not the entire device display.
You set the `@Preview` on the Greeting function, which contain just a `Text()` element, and that's what you got in the preview panel.
You can wrap your `Text` with a `Column` or `Box` and tell Compose to fill the entire screen with a `modifier`.

```
Box(
   Modifier.fillMaxSize()
){
   Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}
```

Note that even on your device, the text does not fill the entire screen, it is only placed in the first available space. Everything works fine.

Comment: The code isn't mine, it's the Android Studio Template's code.  So I was wondering why the preview wasn't displaying the same way that the final app displays.  
Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't actually compile.  There is an error on fillMaxSize(). You can see what the error looks like in android studio in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIhqY.png

Comment: Hi @raddevus , where are your `Box` and `Modifier` coming from? Check your imports. However this is an [example from the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxSize(kotlin.Float)) . You can also try with `Column` instead of `Box` , but I think you imported the wrong modifier.